# Spring Security default login form doesn't get replaced with custom login page

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

How do I remove default login page as first page when application starts running? I am building an ecommerce website whose homepage with some products in it cab be viewed by everyone and only the dashboard should be available after login which should be based on role viz. USER or ADMIN

I have disabled httpBasic as I want first landing page i.e. home page to everyone and also I want to use custom login page but when used in browser "/login" it lands on default login page

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    
    
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().disable();
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/login");
        
    }
}
```

In maincontroller class I have RequestMapping for "/login" to redirect to my custom page

```
@Controller
public class mainController {
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String registration() {
        return "login-register";
    }
    @GetMapping("/my-account")
    public String account() {
        return "my-account";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the name of your login page should match with your return values in your controller.
I mean if your login page is like this: `login.html` your controller method should be like below.

```java
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
```

But If the problem still exists try to modify your configuration method.

```java
        http
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login");
```